# React-router-dom does not scroll to top of page

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm going crazy, I'm using react-router-dom, the moment I go from page A to B I want it to start at the top of the page, everywhere. I've tried different things like:

```
componentDidUpdate(){
      console.log('hello');
      document.documentElement.scrollTo(0, 0)
  }
```

&

```
componentDidUpdate(){
      console.log('hello');
      window.scrollTo(0, 0)
  }
```

&

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

function ScrollToTop({ history }) {
   useEffect(() => {
     const unlisten = history.listen(() => {
       window.scrollTo(0, 0);
     });
     return() => {
       unlist();
     }
   }, []);

   return(null);
}

export default withRouter(ScrollToTop);
```

But unfortunately without success, is there anyone who can tell me what I can do? I'm using :`react": "^16.14.0"`

So the intention is if I click on a `<Link to={'../shopping cart'}>Shopping cart</Link>` I will end up at the top of the page!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use useRef hook. something like this:

```
  const linkRef = useRef(null);
   
       useEffect(() => {
          if (linkRef.current) {
             linkRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' });
          }
       }, []);

         return <Link ref={linkRef} to='/shopping-card' />
```